# Eclipse plug-in (OpenEdge Architect 10.2B) blocked by firewall

Tags: eclipse, plugins

Yesterday I installed OpenEdge Architect 10.2B (that is Object Oriented Progress adopted to Eclipse IDE) on my Windows 7 premium platform. The installation went fine without any error messages.

- When I start OpenEdge Architect I get the following error message:
  "Not licensed to run OpenEdge Architect for version 10.2B". 
  This error message is not the case,
- Also, it seems like parts of the Eclipse-plugin are blocked

  (1) The main menu looks ok

  (2) In the views there are error messages like "Could not create the view: Plug-in com.openedge.pdt.text was unable to load class com.openedge.pdt.text.explorer.OEExplorer."

I noted that if I open my firewall (F-Secure) and choose to allow all, then everything works fine but then, of course, the computer is vulnerable. Then I thought I should abandon the F-secure firewall and use Windows firewall instead, setting up exceptions for OE Architect. But at this point I can not see what the exceptions should be since there are plenty of processes involved!

Any suggestion on how to proceed? How can I see what is blocked (is it Eclipse related or Eclipse plug-in related or is it something else in the OpenEdge package?)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using OE Architect 10.x on the Windows platform for several years without too many issues. I've experienced problems when our corporate antivirus software (McAfee) blocks or scans Java processes, causing Eclipse to hang. In most cases, Eclipse will eventually respond, but it has caused crashes in the past. I've also used OE Architect/Eclipse with the default Windows firewall settings without any issues so I'd try that first. If your PC is connected to a router, you should be pretty safe with Windows Firewall. Good luck.